# Sympy discriminant of polynomial with variable coefficients involving floats

Tags: python, sympy

I wish to figure out when two ellipses first intersect, as their 'radii' increase. They should be externally cotangent at that instant. We have two functions f and g, both of the form a x^2+b y^2+ c xy +d x+f y+(e-t). Note the variable t in the constant term. f, g(x,y) = 0 describes the 1st, 2nd ellipse of 'radius' t.  Contangent curves means double root. My approach: cancel the y^2 terms and then solve for y as a rational function of x. Substitute this into f, and clear denominators: this yields a quartic polynomial in x with coefficients involving t (of which x is a zero). Now I should be able to use discriminants to figure out the t values for which that polynomial has a double root, recovering the smallest t for which the ellipses are cotangent.

I tried a simple example in a sympy live shell, where the a,b etc involved in f and g were integers. After some trial and error, I got the following to work:

```
f = 2*x**2+y**2-t
g = 3*(1/sqrt(2)*(x-1)+1/sqrt(2)*(y+1))**2+5*(1/sqrt(2)*(x-1)-1/sqrt(2)*(y+1))**2-t
h = expand(g).coeff(y,2)*f - expand(f).coeff(y,2)*g
h = Poly(h)
f2=Poly((f.subs(y, solve(h,y)[0])*h.as_expr().coeff(y,1)**2).simplify(),x)
roots = roots(discriminant(f2),t)
```

After discarding the complex roots, I had what I wanted. How do I get this to work with non-integer inputs?

My attempts: the first issue is that multiplying by `h.as_expr().coeff(y,1)**2` fails to cancel the denominator in `f.subs(y, solve(h,y)[0])` presumably due to rounding error. I crafted a workaround via extracting the numerator and denominator of the expression separately, replacing substitution with a coefficient-by-coefficient operation:

```
num = -1*h.as_expr().coeff(y,0)
denom = h.as_expr().coeff(y,1)
noYTerm = f.as_expr().coeff(y,0)
linearYTerm = f.as_expr().coeff(y,1)
ySquareTerm = f.as_expr().coeff(y,2)
f2 = Poly(simplify(ySquareTerm*num**2+linearYTerm*num*denom+noYTerm*denom**2),x)
```

However, I just get a bunch of `sympy.polys.polyerrors.PolynomialDivisionFailed` errors. If I print off the expression for f2, I get
`Poly(10108.448*x**3 + 155858.976*x**2 + (707853.024000001 - 949.184000000001*t)*x + 918397.152000001 - 6870.336*t, x, domain='RR[t]')`
The `.000001` screams floating point error...I've tried switching to QQ, but still little success.

I'm also open to other approaches: perhaps there's an easier way to extract the information I want from this pair of polynomials than what I'm doing.

Comment: Replace the coefficients with rational approximations or representations at the start. Or use a numerical solver (from scipy.optimize) without using sympy. Afaik there are no "hybrid" solver methods implemented in the standard python packages.

Comment: Is there no way to make this work with floats?

Comment: There is, see Kalthofen (and others) about approximative resultants, essentially, this does a dimension analysis on the SVD of the Sylvester matrix. It is just not something that is implemented in sympy.

Comment: Also: I don't see how a numerical solver would help. I'm solving for the t-values such that the (x,y) system has a double root. Until I have some expression for "these are the t values with a double root" (discriminant 0) I don't see how a numerical solver is applicable

Comment: What should work is to solve this problem first with variables as coefficients, and then substitute those in the result against their floating-point values.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I changed the polynomials to having variable coefficients. However, it seems to get stuck on calculating the discriminant (> 15 minutes processing time)

Comment: Yes, that is the downside of it, the more algebraic variables there are, the more complicated the intermediate expressions can become. Note that the coefficient field for the resultant computation is the function field (rational expressions) in the coefficient-variables. I do not know if sympy implements the sub-resultant algorithm that reduces this overhead somewhat. You could try a mature CAS like Magma, there is an online-calculator.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing as suggested. By plugging a particular t into the quartic and checking for positive real roots, you can see if the ellipses intersect at a certain size. I then did a binary search to find the smallest t value at which the ellipses first intersect.

Later, I realized an inelegant workaround: there's an explicit expression for the quartic discriminant, at https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolynomialDiscriminant.html. So I spent 10 minutes typing that into my program. Then I could plug in the coefficients of f_2:

```
a0 = f2.coeff(x,0) # a1 =...etc.
# formula for quartic discriminant from https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolynomialDiscriminant.html
discr = Poly( a1**2*a2**2*a3**2 - 4*a1**3*a3**3 - 4*a1**2*a2**3*a4 + 18*a1**3*a2*a3*a4-27*a1**4*a4**2 + 256*a0**3*a4**3
       + a0*(-4*a2**3*a3**2 + 18*a1*a2*a3**3 + 16*a2**4*a4 - 80*a1*a2**2*a3*a4 - 6*a1**2*a3**2*a4 + 144*a1**2*a2*a4**2)
       + a0**2 * (-27*a3**4 + 144* a2* a3**2 * a4 - 128 * a2**2 * a4**2 - 192 * a1 * a3 * a4**2)), t)
roots = np.roots(discr.all_coeffs())
postiveAndReal  = numpy.logical_and(numpy.isreal(roots), numpy.greater(roots, numpy.zeros(roots.shape[0])))
firstIntersectAt = numpy.amin(roots[postiveAndReal])
```

However, it seems like expanding that massive expression creates rounding error. With this method, if the ellipses were ~0.1 apart, sometimes I'd get errors due to taking amin of an empty list. The binary search method seems to be the way to go, then.